# Which motion sensor do I have to use?

Tags: kotlin, sensors, accelerometer

I have a homework in which the app has to detect the movement either I move my phone, to the right, left, up or down

I tried to use the accelerometer, but following the Android Studio documentation It only detects movement when my phone is laying down in a static position and I need to move my phone not in It's own axis but in different directions